# Javascript: Scope issues in object

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, prototype

I cannot access certain variables from a function. Here's what I got:

```
var PTP = function (properties) {
    this.errorsArray = []
}


PTP.prototype.initHTMLItems = function () {
    $('input[data-widget-type="date"]').each(this.dateValidation)
}


PTP.prototype.dateValidation = function() {
    var field = '#' + $(this)[0].id
    var that = this
    $(field).focusout(function(){
        var valid = form_validate_date($(field).val())
        var label = $('#date').siblings('label').children('.label-text').text()

        if (!valid) {
            that.errorsArray.push({
                'field': field,
                'fieldType': 'date',
                'errorMessage': 'Incorrect data' + (label !== undefined ? ' for ' + label : "")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

The issue is that I cannot access errorsArray.

I also tried passing a callback function as a parameter to dateValidation:

```
PTP.prototype.addError = function(errorObj) {
    this.errorsArray.push(errorObj)
}
```

Tried this way:

```
PTP.prototype.initHTMLItems = function () {
    $('input[data-widget-type="date"]').each(this.dateValidation(this.addError))
}
```

and also this way:

```
PTP.prototype.initHTMLItems = function () {
    $('input[data-widget-type="date"]').each(this.dateValidation.bind(this.addError))
}
```

but that screwed with the scope of **this** in dateValidation:

```
PTP.prototype.dateValidation = function(callback) {
    var field = '#' + $(this)[0].id
    var that = this
    $(field).focusout(function(){
        var valid = form_validate_date($(field).val())
        var label = $('#date').siblings('label').children('.label-text').text()

        if (!valid) {
            callback({
                'field': field,
                'fieldType': 'date',
                'errorMessage': 'Incorrect data' + (label !== undefined ? ' for ' + label : "")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

How can I get access to errorsArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change
`$('input[data-widget-type="date"]').each(this.dateValidation)`

to

```
$('input[data-widget-type="date"]').each(function(index, element) {
  this.dateValidation(element);
}.bind(this));
```

and then change `PTP.prototype.dateValidation = function(callback) {`

to `PTP.prototype.dateValidation = function(element) {`
now, inside dateValidation, `this` is your PTP object, and `element` is the jquery element from your each loop

Comment: If I bind to 'this', I get access to errorsArray but I lose access to the current field I'm working on, meaning that var field = '#' + $(this)[0].id won't work

Comment: @MrCujo: ah this is a very annoying part of the jquery api. I'll update my answer (tl;dr you should pass both parameters in)

Comment: @MrCujo: updated

Comment: it worked indeed. I appreciate very much your time. Thanks! Just wondering, could it be possible to solve this issue with a closure to preserver the scope?